# VSCode cannot find TypeScript modules and types in my project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've got a project that uses TypeScript. It works fine from the command line, but when I open it in VSCode it complains about not being able to find various modules and types:

[image]
[image]

The file structure is:

```
- app/
  - javascript/
    - src/
      - app_reducer.ts
- spec/
  - javascript/
    - _test_helpers
      - factories.ts
- tsconfig.json
- tsconfig-test.json
```

This complaint is coming from a file `factories.ts`. `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig-test.json` are:

```
{
  "//": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["app/javascript/src/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "spec",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["app/javascript/src/*"],
      "_test_helpers/*": ["spec/javascript/_test_helpers/*"]
    }
  },
  "extends": "./tsconfig",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

And from the command line it works fine when I run:

```sh
yarn tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig-test.json
```

Comment: please show your tree structure of files

Comment: if app_reducer is in src and the file referencing it is in spec then you want "../src/app_reducer"

Comment: I added more information about the file structure. We're using the `paths` configuration to allow importing files without needing to specify relative paths like `../`.